# Interaction with Odoo via XML-RPC

Tags: json, xml-rpc, odoo, erp

During my internship i'm told to build a Django application that retrieve data from Odoo via XML-RPC, and from my knowledge the xmlrpc web server support only XML format but when i follow the official documentation from Odoo10 https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html in the "Search and read" section it seems to me like the response is in JSON format ( which is good for me). I'm just wondering if i'm missing something.

Any clarification ? thanks.

Comment: Hi @Imed, I've updated my answer but I have one question, if you want to receive XMLRPC responses in a Django application, don't you prefer to work with Python (since you're receiving Python objects in your XMLRPC queries) instead of JSON?

Comment: Hi, in fact I do want to receive a JSON response and that's what I get. But when I started to write the report of my internship I discovered that XMLRPC return only an XML response which made me confused and that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly JSON, but a Python object (list, dictionary, etc...) ready to be converted to a JSON string through the `dumps` method of the `json` library. Take a look at the behaviour of this Python console working with XMLRPC. First, I made the query (with also `search_read` method). Then I ask for the type of the received result, which is an array (Python object). And then, to convert this Python object to a JSON string, I use `dumps` method. And there you have your JSON.

```
>>> res = models.execute_kw(
    db,
    uid,
    password,
    'res.partner',
    'search_read',
    [[
        ['is_company', '=', True],
        ['customer', '=', True]
    ]],
    {
        'fields': ['name', 'country_id', 'comment'],
        'limit': 5
    }
)

>>> res
[
    {
        'comment': False,
        'country_id': [69, 'Spain'],
        'id': 1665,
        'name': 'Customer A'
    }, {
        'comment': False,
        'country_id': [69, 'Spain'],
        'id': 5799,
        'name': 'Customer B'
    }, {
        'comment': False,
        'country_id': [69, 'Spain'],
        'id': 1946,
        'name': 'Customer C'
    }, {
        'comment': False,
        'country_id': [69, 'Spain'],
        'id': 1367,
        'name': 'Customer D'
    }, {
        'comment': False,
        'country_id': [69, 'Spain'],
        'id': 2066,
        'name': 'Customer E'
    }
]

>>> type(res)
<type 'list'>

>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(res)

'[{"comment": false, "country_id": [69, "Spain"], "id": 1665, "name": "CUSTOMER A"}, {"comment": false, "country_id": [69, "Spain"], "id": 5799, "name": "CUSTOMER B"}, {"comment": false, "country_id": [69, "Spain"], "id": 1946, "name": "CUSTOMER C"}, {"comment": false, "country_id": [69, "Spain"], "id": 1367, "name": "CUSTOMER D"}, {"comment": false, "country_id": [69, "Spain"], "id": 2066, "name": "CUSTOMER E"}]'

>>> your_json = json.dumps(res)  # This variable is ready to be sent as JSON
```

I have updated my answer to clarify it, thanks to @ChesuCR.

Comment: `json.dumps` convert a Python Object (lists, dictionaries, booleans with capital letters...) to a JSON string. On the other hand `json.loads` convert a JSON string to a Python Object. You cannot have a JSON object on Python directly. Convert the python object to string is useful if you want to send it to a external o remote application

Comment: You're right @ChesuCR, I have updated my answer, thank you!